Nothing shows up when I try to access stat page in Nginx RTMP Module (Windows)
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost;

    # This URL provides RTMP statistics in XML
    location /stat {
        if ($request_method = "GET") {
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
        }

        rtmp_stat all;

        # Use this stylesheet to view XML as web page
        # in browser
        rtmp_stat_stylesheet /stat.xsl;
    }

    location /stat.xsl {
        # XML stylesheet to view RTMP stats.
        # Copy stat.xsl wherever you want
        # and put the full directory path here
        # root /path/to/stat.xsl/;
        root "C:\Users\kenrg\OneDrive\Dokumenter\Diverse\RTMPBackup\";

    }

    location /control {
        rtmp_control all;
    }
}

}
I try localhost:80/stat, but nothing shows up.

Is the process running? Also: logs

Yes the process is running.
